# angularjs correct row is not being deleted from table

Tags: angularjs

I have been struggling with a couple of issue so I thought I would reach out for help after doing much searching. I'm using AngularJS.

1. My first problem is that checkbox is not working properly when I use ng-repeat, it will only check the first box in the table code snippet below. I'm using a custom checkbox which I coded with css is the reason for the label.
2. My second issue is when I click on the check box it should delete any row I want but it deletes the row before it if I start from the bottom of the table up, but if I start from the top of the table down it works as expected except for the box being checked code snippet.  I tried many ways to set the index but it still does not work.

$scope.removeRow = function(type) {

```
var index = -1;
var myArr = eval( $scope.contacts );
    for( var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++ ) {
       if( myArr[i].type === type ) {
           index = i;
           break;
             }
      {
if( index === -1 ) {
        alert( "Something gone wrong" );
      } 


    $scope.contacts.splice(index, 1);       
};
```

Comment: You have a break in the for loop when it matches, so it will stop after it hits the first match. That's most likely why it's only checking the first box in the table

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use `eval($scope.contacts)`.  If that variable is a string and contains javascript it will run that javascript. if `myArr` isn't defined using `myArr = $scope.contacts` you can use `myArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.contacts)` or use `angular.copy` method.

I don't see your html, so I can't tell you why your checkbox doesn't work.  But regarding your second problem, if it's deleting a row above when you hit `splice`, why not change that code to :

```
$scope.contacts.splice(index + 1, 1)
```